# Rails 3.1 Timezone UTC and Central Time zone confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, timezone

I am relatively new to RoR and am having trouble with the timezone conversions.  When getting data out of the database (which is stored in US Central time), it believes that the times in there are in UTC and tries to convert them, therefore making them wrong by 5 hours.  I have this in my application.rb file:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

If I remove eiher one of these config directives, the time does not save correctly.  As long as I have them in, the time stores in the database correctly, but RoR cannot read them correctly.  In order to fix this, I have to convert all times that I get from the database to UTC.  I have to believe that there is a better way.

I also tried setting ENV['TZ'], but that didn't seem to do anything.

```
ENV['TZ'] = "US/Central"
```

Any help would be appreaciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any chance of you doing the *sane* thing and changing the data in the database itself so it's all UTC? Storing data all in one particular (non-UTC) time zone is asking for trouble - and it'll lose information too, due to DST transitions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the design decision is out of my hands.  For this project, I was told the time must be stored in US Central time.

Comment: You mean in Central Time, right? Not CST, which is always *standard* time.

Comment: Right, sorry.  I meant US Central time...

Answer (score 0):

For me actually, AR rejected setting value to something else from :utc/:local

```rb
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

this line ended up with log filled with warnings of falling back to :local

What worked is entirely switching system time zone

```rb
ENV['TZ'] = "US/Central"
```

Make sure, to use correct tz name though.
Unix time zone names are not those used by ActiveSupport::TimeZone

Refer to **ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING** for this

Also, note that after this Time.now == Time.current; it will be giving time in specified time zone too;

So this is more kind of a hack than a solution.